# How do you convey this Russian proverb in Italian?

Tags: translation, proverbs

There is a Russian proverb: *я не червонец, чтобы всем нравиться*, that in English means "I'm not a [chervonets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chervonets) (ten-ruble bill) to be liked by everyone". Or, less literally, but a little bit more precisely, "The ten-ruble bill is one thing that is liked by everyone, well, I'm not that".

Its meaning is "I'm putting my personal goals above people's approval, so I'm a kind of person who's ok with doing something people won't like".

Two questions (hope that's ok because they are closely related):

1. How do you translate the original to Italian (mutatis mutandis)? My take is: *non sono un centomila lire cosicché mi vogliano bene tutti*, but this sounds off.
2. Is there an Italian proverb with a similar meaning? *Bisogna che si levi di buon'ora chi desidera piacere a tutti* is close, but this means "you can't be liked by everyone", and I'm looking for "It's not my goal to be liked by everyone".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si usa dire *non si può piacere a tutti*, che ha una componente di orgoglio, del tipo 'non mi interessa piacere a tutti'.

La citazione completa (notare il riferimento a Zeus, a proposito di orgoglio):

*Non si può piacere a tutti. Ma in questo non c'è niente di strano. Anche Zeus, che mandi la pioggia o la neghi, non a tutti piace.*

Fonte: https://le-citazioni.it/frasi/216686-teognide-non-si-puo-piacere-a-tutti-ma-in-questo-non-ce-n/

Un altro modo di dire, che va bene in alcuni contesti, è *non sono un uomo per tutte le stagioni*, per dire 'non mi adatto a tutto per compiacere gli altri'.

Vedi ad esempio:

https://video.corriere.it/spettacoli/fazio-l-addio-rai-non-sono-uomo-tutte-stagioni/718f7bdc-f28d-11ed-a4b3-4ddf09c7299d

Per quanto riguarda la traduzione in italiano del proverbio,  la traduzione con *cosicché* è pesante e il congiuntivo non va bene, e anche l'uso di *voler bene*, suona strano riferito a una banconota.

Io tradurrei:  ***non sono un biglietto da centomila lire che piaccio a tutti.***

Tenendo presente che ora le lire non ci sono più, ma nei modi di dire si possono usare, ad esempio si dice *non ho una lira*. Anche perché, a quanto ho capito, anche *chervonets* è un nome antico.